# Size of access.log and server load?

Tags: linux, apache

Is there any difference at all in server load when adding new lines to a big vs. small access.log file?

What I mean is, should I delete my access.log files if they become too big or leave it.  It is 6GB right now. I do not rotate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the performance difference of big or small files, but maybe you want to split them every month and compress old access-log files. For that you can use logrotate. More information in the [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

Comment: If you had to guess, would you say there is a performance difference?

Comment: I don't think it has big influence to add a new line in the end of a file. But maybe you could get space problems if the file gets to big. And if you rotate your logs, you can set different rules to delete old logs and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Log rotation is an important part of maintaining a server. Without it, you'r likely to fill up your disk, and then your server will behave extremely strangely, depending on the app.

Regardless of performance, you should be using `logrotate` or something similar.